# how can i get a particular word from a line in a file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file with the following text and I want to get the 3rd, 4th value only:

element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/... TPLBASE.

So how can I do it?

Comment: Put here what you've done so far. You can use sed, awk, cut ...

Comment: so far i have a file called raw-vobs-config-spec which has this line "element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_collections/3_2_2/... TPLBASE".....so what i need is i want only /open_source/commons_collections from this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear from your question how would you define a *word* in your situation. If you just want the 3rd and 4th directories of your path, here's how you do it:

```
cat $FILE | cut -d'/' -f3,4
```

Comment: the complete scenario in my case is- i have a file raw-vobs-config-spec where i have many lines.some of them are                                      element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/jsoncpp/0_5_0/...                                                                                         element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/commons_net/2_0/                                                                     element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/open_source/javacsv/2_0/

Comment: If this file looks always the same, just use cut. Set the indices for the `-f` accordingly.

Comment: how can i do that..i am new to shell scripting...:(

Comment: Like I said, `cat raw-vobs-config-spec | cut -d'/' -f4,5` if you want entries like `open_source/smth`.